# Marshalling exception with code from the ShareTarget second window

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm having a hard time with some code I have that apparently struggles when called from the second window created by the ShareTarget contract (when you share something to the app, it opens in a small standalone window).

This is my code so far:

```
// Blur and resize the image to get the average HSL color
// Assume that stream is an IRandomAccessStream pointing to valid image data
HslColor hslMean;
using (RandomAccessStreamImageSource imageProvider = new RandomAccessStreamImageSource(stream))
using (BlurEffect blurEffect = new BlurEffect(imageProvider) { KernelSize = 256 })
{
    Color mean = await DispatcherHelper.GetFromUIThreadAsync(async () =>
    {
        WriteableBitmap
            blurred = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight),
            result = await blurEffect.GetBitmapAsync(blurred, OutputOption.Stretch),
            resized = result.Resize(1, 1, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
        return resized.GetPixel(0, 0);
    });
    hslMean = mean.ToHsl();
}
```

**Note**: that `DispatcherHelper.GetFromUIThreadAsync` method just checks the thread access to the UI thread, and if needed it schedules the code to a `CoreDispatcher` object that was obtained with `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher`.

> **Problem**: this code works 100% fine if my app is already open, as at that point that `CoreDispatcher` object has already been created by previous calls to that `DispatcherHelper` class, so the method just uses the stored dispatcher to schedule the work and it works fine. *But*, if the app is closed when the ShareTarget window is opened (so that `DispatcherHelper` has to create the dispatcher for the first time) the `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow` line throws an exception. A very weird one:
>
> > `COMException`:
> >     A COM call to an ASTA was blocked because the call chain originated in or passed through another ASTA. This call pattern is deadlock-prone and disallowed by apartment call control.
> >     A COM call (IID: {638BB2DB-451D-4661-B099-414F34FFB9F1}, method index: 6) to an ASTA (thread 10276) was blocked because the call chain originated in or passed through another ASTA (thread 4112). This call pattern is deadlock-prone and disallowed by apartment call control.

---

So, I needed a way to make that method reliable even when being called from different windows. I've tried different options:

**#1**: Just invoking that code without dispatching to a different thread, as in theory I should be on the UI thread at this point ---> **FAIL** (The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)))

**#2**: Manually calling `CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` to dispatch that code block ---> **FAIL** (I get that weird `COMException` mentioned above)

**#3**: Manually using `CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher` to dispatch the code block (as it was the `.CoreWindow` part that spawned the exception) ---> **FAIL** (`COMException`: item not found)

**#4**: Using `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.Dispatcher`, `CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().Dispatcher`, `Window.Current.CoreWindow.Dispatcher` and `Window.Current.Content.Dispatcher` to schedule that code ---> **FAIL** (wrong thread again, I get the usual marshalling exception)

All these marshalling exception are thrown at the line `result = await blurEffect.GetBitmapAsync(blurred, OutputOption.Stretch)`, so I suspect it might be something related to the Lumia Imaging SDK.
I mean, I'm quite sure that I am in fact on the UI thread, or otherwise I wouldn't have managed to create an instance of the `WriteableBitmap` class, right?

> Why is it that I can create `WriteableBitmap` objects (and they need to be created on the UI thread as far as I know), but that `GetBitmapAsync` method from the Lumia SDK always throws that marshalling exception? I'm using it everywhere in my app without any problems, why is it that it just won't work from the ShareTarget window? Is there anything I need to do?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in the Lumia Imaging SDK (that was originally written for WP8.1, which didn't have multiple windows/dispatchers), so unless the call to the library is made from the dispatcher associated with the main app window (which of course can only be retrieved if the app is open in the background when the ShareTarget window pops up), it will just fail.

The only solution at this point is to replace that call to the Lumia SDK with some other code that doesn't rely on that particular library (in this case for example, it is possible to just get the ARGB array from the `WriteableBitmap` object and calculate the mean color manually).

Comment: @Scavenger Yup, I was just waiting for the accept feature to be available, as I posted the solution less than 48 hours after the initial question, thanks for the reminder!